# Точная длина значения переменной double

Tags: c++

Нужно сделать матрицу используя в ячейках значения с плавающей запятой,но проблема в том что я не нашел коротких и достойных способов точно определить длинну double : через to_string().size() режет,через перенос в char - долго.

Comment: Гм... а что вы понимаете под "длиной `double`"?...

Comment: количество знаков,учитывая точку,или хотя бы без нее

Comment: *"через перенос в char - долго"* Сомневаюсь, что без него можно обойтись. Я бы перевел в строку, сохранил эту строку, а потом напечатал. Нет, можно сделать `std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, "%f", число)`, но оно скорее всего под капотом будет переводить в строку, а делать это два раза - не очень.

Comment: *"количество знаков,учитывая точку,или хотя бы без нее"* Это количество зависит от параметров преобразования в строку.

Comment: Количество знаков определяется точностью представления, грубо говоря. И сделать **точное** число, например, 0.2 не получится - потому что на самом деле оно будет представлено как 0.2000000000000000111... - сколько знаков считать здесь?...

Comment: тогда можно ли ограничить количество выводимых символов определенной переменной?

Comment: Конечно. Например, `printf("%.12lf",d);`, или там `cout << setprecision(12) << d;`

Comment: @Harry, в C точность тоже можно переменной задавать: `printf("%.*f", 12, d);`

Comment: Спасибо за ответы,нашел еще 1 способ - установка флага на cout : cout.setf(ios::fixed);.Даже после переноса в строку значения длины с простым выводом совпадают.